# Change style of progressbar javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

The default appearance of a [`ProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/control/ProgressBar.html) is a blue bar that moves across the control as the progress increases:

[image]

I have an image (of a train) as a resource in my application. Is it possible, using CSS (or another technique) to have the image progress across the control instead of the default blue bar? It should look something like:

[image]

Comment: How can this be closed as "unclear what you're asking" when I already answered it with essentially four lines of code? While English is obviously not the OP's first language, what (s)he is asking is abundantly clear. I note that not one of the people who voted to close has a single post in a question with a JavaFX tag. Voting to reopen.

Comment: After being edited by James_D this question is no more unclear and deserves reversing the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an external CSS file and set a background image on the bar. The bar itself is represented by a `Region` with style class `bar` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#progressbar)), so you just need something like

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Train_icon_small.png");
    -fx-background-position: right ;
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat-x ;
}
```

Complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TrainProgressBar extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        Button startButton = new Button("Start");
        startButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            startButton.setDisable(true);
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                        updateProgress(i, 100);
                    }
                    updateProgress(100, 100);
                    return null ;
                }
            };
            progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
            task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> startButton.setDisable(false));
            new Thread(task){{setDaemon(true);}}.start();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(15, progressBar, startButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 100);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("train-progress-bar.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with train-progress-bar.css:

```
.root {
    -fx-padding: 10 ;
    -fx-alignment: center ;
}

.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Train_icon_small.png);
    -fx-background-position: right ;
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat-x ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I mirror the image in css?

Answer (score 1):

```
   .parentOfProgress {
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    width: 144px;
}
progress {
    height:5px !important;
    background: #fafafa !important;
}

    progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
        background: #fafafa !important;
        height: 5px !important;
    }

    progress::-webkit-progress-value {
        background: #06c !important;
    }

    progress::-moz-progress-bar {
        background: #fafafa !important;
        height: 5px !important;
    }
```